# network answers in Careers should have bounty information, too

Tags: feature-request, jobs, answers, bounties, accepted-answer

It appears that Careers shows whether an answer was accepted or not (in addition to the vote count), but doesn't show whether a bounty was won.  That could be improved.

Additionally, it's very difficult to add more answers to the Careers profile -- the drop-down menu for selectively adding each answer individually (which appears to be he only way to add more answers) is missing acceptance state (even though it's shown after you add it).